# PyQt5 QtreeWidget : How can i access a custom widget's methods in a QtreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidgetitem

I have a simple QTreeWidget  :

```
self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget(self)
col = ("Status", "Name")
self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(2)
self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(col)
```

witch I populate using :

```
wid = Custom_Widget()
item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
item.setText(1, "some string")
item.treeWidget().setItemWidget(item, 0, wid)
```

I can easly acces the text column by using :

```
root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
it = root.child(2) # for example the third item
it.setText(1, "Edited")
```

what i need is to edit the costum_widget in column 0, so how can i access it or invoke his methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by keeping a list of all the costum_widgets that i create, my code would be :

```
from CustomWidgets import Custom_Widget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MyExample(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget(self)
        self.group_wid = []  # my list of widgets
        col = ("Status", "Name")
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(col)

        self.populate_tree()
        self.edit_tree()
        self.show()

    def populate_tree(self):
        for i in range(10):
            wid = Custom_Widget()
            self.group_wid.append(wid)  # each time i instantiate a Custom_Widget i'll add it to my list of widgets
            item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
            item.setText(1, "some string")
            item.treeWidget().setItemWidget(item, 0, wid)

    def edit_tree(self):
        root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
        it = root.child(2)  # for example the third item
        it.setText(1, "Edited")
        self.group_wid[2].my_method()  # i can easily edit my widgets that are in the QTreeWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyExample()
    app.exec_()
```

Guess the QtreeWidgetItem only hold a reference to the widgets that are contained.